# prevent absolute file path in Content-Disposition "filename"

Tags: c++, forms, cgi, filenames, content-disposition

I have a simple HTML Form

```
<form id="uploadForm" method="post" action="/cgi-bin/test.cgi" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="submit" name="add_something" value="add">
   <input size="50" type="file" name="myFile" accept="application/zip">
</form>
```

In addition I do some web page localization on server side by checking user browser locale or searching for a self set language session cookie.

If I upload a file with

- Iron 18.0.1050.0
- Opera 11.64.1403
- Firefox 3.6.27
- Firefox 12.0
- Google Chrome 19.0.1084.52
- SeaMonkey 2.9.1

all works fine. But If I upload a file with

- IE 9.0.8112.16421
- Maxton 3.3.8.3000

the localization fails. I detected the issue inside the HTTP request:

Opera 11

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myFile"; filename="ziptest.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip
```

and IE 9

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myFile"; filename="C:\Documents and Settings\m1krsch\Documents\Now Some Spaces\ziptest.zip"
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed
```

If I remove the spaces from the path all works fine in IE and Maxton.

Neighter can I exchange the used cgicc library because it is fixed part of the project nor can I force a user to use a path without spaces. How can I circumvent this issue? Is there a way to force IE/Maxton to use the filename instead of the abolute filepath? Or can I set a specific parameter in cgi/env to prevent transmission of abolute filepath?

[EDIT]
I found out that this is a security issue in IE and Maxton. The security zone model of IE allows by default to "Include local directory path when uploading files". I can disallow this behaviour only by changing the client configuration but I am still searching for an application-based solution.
[/EDIT]

Comment: I find myself wanting your question "Edit" as another answer. It really does provide a useful answer to the broader question. I'd vote it up :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a stupid error in my localization code. I am using RapidXML for this and encapsulate the whole localization code and RapidXML headers in one class. Unfortunately I did not read the documentation very careful. The data inside `vector<char>` object - which is holding the XML document data - is not copied into the XML document object `xml_document<>` by using the `parse()` method as expected. This looks like procedural C code to me and is in my opinion bad OOD. The documentation says:

> 3.1 Lifetime Of Source Text
>
> In-situ parsing requires that source text lives at least as long as the document object.

The problem vanished when I corrected my code to get a global `vector<char>` object inside my localization class.

Nevertheless I am perplexed why mostly all other browsers have no problem with my old code.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the spaces with `'%20'`:

```
"C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\m1krsch\Documents\Now%20Some%20Spaces\ziptest.zip"
```

Comment: I tried this by using JacvaScript to change the value field of the form input "myFile" but it does not work. Currently I found a unsatisfactory workaround by changing the setting of the IE security zone "local intranet" to not "Include local directory path when uploading files". But I do not want to reconfigure each client PC. I need a application-based solution instead of a configurable solution.